# Trying to run tensorflow graphics home page demo from comamnd line throws an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am a bit of a ML / TF / Python noob but have made good progress. i.e. can train basic models and use for inference with TF 2.13 - non gpu version.

While trying to run the example here - [TensorFlow Graphics](https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics) , I am encoutering an error -

```
~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_graphics/notebooks/threejs_visualization.py", line 74, in build_context
    _publish.javascript(url=threejs_url + 'three.min.js')
NameError: name '_publish' is not defined
```

I think the sample is missing a step but I am clueless how it can be fixed.

Is it supposed to run only inside jupyter notebook ?

I am trying it on command line. How can I run it ?

Comment: Two same but very old GitHub issues ([issue1](https://github.com/tensorflow/graphics/issues/56) and [issue2](https://github.com/tensorflow/graphics/issues/4)) told that there's no support for Jupyter.

Comment: @doneforaiur I am trying to run it from ubuntu command line.. no jupyer

Comment: It won't work in the terminal AFAIK. Colab is not identical to the Jupyter, so that's why I clarified in my previous comment.